# UINavigationBar failing to change color

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to change the background color / bar tint color of my nav bars programatically.

I have tried several examples, but some required writing code in every view controller which doesn't make the most sense to me, as I would like to have it subclassed to reduce repeated code.

I created a subclass of UINavigationBar (as I also wanted to change the height).

I have successfully changed the height and it works in my application. However, when changing the color, it doesn't appear to work.

```
class Navbars: UINavigationBar {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //self.backgroundColor = Logic.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xff0864, alp: 1.0)
    //self.barTintColor = Logic.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xff0864, alp: 1.0)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    self.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

}

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 205)
}
}
```

The height changes, so I presumed having the code to change it's color in the init function would work, but it doesn't, and I'm not sure why.

I even then tried to subclass UINavigationController and still nothing happens.

```
class NavControllers: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.brown

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

If anyone knows where I am going wrong, that would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code

```
////////////////// set navigation bar tint color ///////////////
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = (your color here);
```

Worked for me :) .

Answer (score 0):

Trying the following in a playground works fine for me…

```
class NavController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
    }
}

let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.view.backgroundColor = .white

let navController = NavController(rootViewController: viewController)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who update xcode to version 11.04, these solutions do not work.That is why, add this code in viewWillAppear

```
guard let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {fatalError("Navigation controller does not exists.")}

let bgColor = UIColor.red // change your choice

navBar.backgroundColor = bgColor
navBar.standardAppearance.backgroundColor = bgColor
navBar.scrollEdgeAppearance?.backgroundColor = bgColor
```